# Trying to write a stored procedure and bind the result in view in a table

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle

I am trying to call a procedure in given below fashion and want to bind the result coming from the procedure in a table in view side.

I have created a procedure `GetData` and want to return value a in dataset and bind in view side without using model.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Getdata(v_hr_stk_out OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) Is
r_stk  number;
vr_stk number;
BEGIN
select round(sum(a.batch_wt)) into r_stk from dbprod.sm_data a where a.iss_date is null and a.cw_coil_no is not null and a.prod_cd = '37' and a.from_plant != a.hsource;
select round(sum(a.batch_wt)) into vr_stk  from dbprod.psm_data a where a.iss_date is null and a.cw_coil_no is not null and a.prod_cd = 'C9' and a.from_plant != a.hr_source;

OPEN v_hr_stk_out For 
select r_stk, vr_stk from dual

END;
```

C# code:

```
conn.Open();

OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandText = "Getdata";
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

command.Parameters.Add("v_hr_stk_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.Parameters.Add("v_cr_stk_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(command);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);

return View("Home", ds)
```

View

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B/th>
        <th>C</th>        
    </tr>
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>F</td>
            <td>@row["r_stk"]</td> 
            <td>@row["vr_stk"]</td>                        
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

**Expected**: value should be returned from `GetData` stored procedure and should be bound in table in view side.

**Actual**: stuck in stored procedure syntax getting error and after getting data binding on view side code is appropriate or not have doubt.

[image]
I am new to Oracle and ASP.NET MVC, trying to do it. Any idea would be appreciated

Comment: Is the procedure compiled successfully and returning the expected result when executed from SQL Developer or SQL*Plus or any other tool?

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 getting error PLS-00103 i.e following  1.encountered symbol "round" expecting.... 2.encountered symbol "Into" expecting ....3.encountered symbol "A" expecting

Comment: add `;` (semicolon) at the end of `select r_stk, vr_stk from dual`

Comment: @Tejash----ORA-00980 still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and share the compilation error screenshot or details?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Windows CRLF characters on line breaks or at spaces. Oracle does not treat this as white space, instead, it sees it as an empty string. In order to get around this problem, convert the CRLF characters to LF characters and Oracle should be happy.

You can use Notepad++ to find these characters. OR simply use notepad and remove all spaces and newline and then recreate the spaces and newline.

Share the result after this activity.